# Yammer - how to authorize another domain

Tags: yammer

I have the Enterprise Edition of Yammer.
I know you can individually invite guests but I read that you can authorize an entire domain to have access to your network.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out this has to be done by contacting Yammer themselves. They then send you a document which you have to sign and send back. And yes I am serious :(